# optimized_execution() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pytorch, amazon-sagemaker

I'm following the pytorch sagemaker docs [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elastic-inference/latest/developerguide/ei-pytorch-using.html) and I'm stuck on this line

`torch.jit.optimized_execution(True, {'target_device': 'eia:device ordinal'})`

When I run it, I get the error `optimized_execution() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`. I'm using pytorch 1.3.1, but I tried with 1.4.0 and was running into similar problems. Can I use optimized execution without this second argument? How can I specify the accelerator?

Answer (score 4):

(I'll refer to the Elastic Inference enabled PyTorch framework as "PyTorch-EI" for convenience)

Are you using SageMaker through notebook or hosting? SageMaker notebook support is not currently released, so there's no official notebook kernel / Conda environment that you can activate that will have the Elastic Inference enabled PyTorch framework. You could however create your own by activating the `pytorch_p36` environment (which has standard PyTorch), uninstalling PyTorch, and then installing using the [PyTorch-EI 1.3.1 framework wheel](https://s3.console.aws.amazon.com/s3/buckets/amazonei-pytorch/) - linked from [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elastic-inference/latest/developerguide/basics.html).

SageMaker hosting does currently support PyTorch-EI out of the box. If you're currently using SageMaker hosting and having issues, share some of your inference code + what container you're using. List of containers can be found at [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/deep-learning-containers/latest/devguide/deep-learning-containers-images.html).

Also note that EC2 currently supports Elastic Inference through the DLAMI v27.0. The Conda environment name is `amazonei_pytorch_p36`.

Answer (score 0):

I misread the documentation. It says `the Elastic Inference enabled PyTorch framework accepts two parameters for this context, while the vanilla PyTorch framework accepts only one parameter.`. It should work for torch 1.3.1 because that is all sagemaker supports as of now.